# What should be the status of questions about domestic appliances?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, scope

[This question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/9112/my-dish-washer-button-stop-operating) on a fault with dishwasher turned up today.

We've had a few, but not many, questions in the past, but I noticed that the FAQ (recently updated by me!) doesn't make any mention of such questions one way or the other.

So should we allow such questions or not?

The FAQ can be updated appropriately.

Comment: OK - based on the answers so far there seems to be a consensus so I'll update the FAQ.

Comment: I'd agree with Steve's [comment in the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2584650#2584650) to change the definition to "major" appliances.

Comment: @BMitch - OK - I'll update the FAQ. We don't need to define "major" do we?

Comment: we could point people to the google search. I personally like the limit of attached fixtures to the home, but in different areas, people detach things that I wouldn't upon moving.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Operation = no.

Installation, maintenance and repair questions should be allowed as long as they're DIY/home improvement tasks. Most of our appliances integrate closely with the house structure -- plumbing, HVAC, or electrical -- and those questions are always interesting and honored. Water heaters, for instance, count as an "appliance" and there are numerous helpful and interesting questions about them. Where questions don't meet the DIY test (such as recharging a fridge with coolant, which is not a DIY task), they should be closed.

Answer (score 4):

If it is about the *operation* of the appliance, I don't think so.

If it is about the *installation* of the appliance, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with @Karl and @Jeff.

The FAQ should also probably be clear about the installation nature of the appliance.  Repairing a toaster seems out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe everything can be so black and white. An example is [this question I asked earlier today](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/93522/saeco-minuto-showing-empty-water-error):

- The question itself suggests it's a hardware problem.
- The answer reveals some steps that the user can follow to resolve it through operation.

I feel there's a need for a Q&A for appliances:

1. Appliances for which manuals are no longer available online;
2. Resolving problems with appliances that aren't covered in the manual;
3. Installation recommendations;
4. Disassembly and/or repair.

I'm of course no authority; I haven't contributed much to this community, so would appreciate input from others.

Comment: I agree that an appliance repair Q&A would be useful. Unfortunately, for it to succeed you need a knowledgeable core user base to answer questions.  It's doubtful that you'll find a user base that can cover the trillion or so devices that could possibly exist. When the SE network first started, there was a Gadgets site, where you could ask questions about any gadget under the sun.  It was one of the first sites to fail. While there was an endless supply of questions, there wasn't anybody to answer them.